# Push GET object to empty object inside data return

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following vue app:

```
new Vue({
    name: 'o365-edit-modal-wrapper',
    el: '#o365-modal-edit-wrapper',
    data: function() {
        return {
            list: {},
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.get_array_of_post_objects(this.list, 'applications');
    },
    methods: {
        get_array_of_post_objects(list, slug) {
            wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
                const Posts = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
                    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'fh/v1/menus/' + slug,
                });
                const all_posts = new Posts();
                all_posts.fetch().then(function(posts) {

                    console.log(posts.data);

                });
            });
        },
    },
});
```

`console.log(posts.data)` outputs the following items:
[image]

How would I assign that object to my empty `list: {}` so that in my template, I can pull it as this:

```
<button class="button" v-for="app in list.selected" :key="app.order">
```

All help will be appreciated! I keep getting an undefined item back each time I attempt to push the items.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have to work with JS, I always prefer `ES6` syntax.
Let me rewrite your code for you and try if it's working or not. I prefer to use arrow functions inside a function.

```js
new Vue({
  name: "o365-edit-modal-wrapper",
  el: "#o365-modal-edit-wrapper",
  data() {
    return {
      list: {},
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.get_array_of_post_objects("applications");
  },
  methods: {
    get_array_of_post_objects(slug) {
      wp.api.loadPromise.done(() => {
        const Posts = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
          url: wpApiSettings.root + "fh/v1/menus/" + slug,
        });
        const all_posts = new Posts();
        all_posts.fetch().then((posts) => {
          console.log(posts.data);
          this.list = posts.data;
        });
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I will also add, using es6 with arrow functions leaves the context of `this` alone which is best when working with vue. easier to assign without binding.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! Looks like it works great, but seems as if vue draggable can't handle single objects with multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Chirag has the answer there. However, I do not recommend using an arrow function as it is not supported by IE, So I would simply just create a separate function to handle the work. this makes the code more readable. So something like this should work:

```
new Vue({
  name: "o365-edit-modal-wrapper",
  el: "#o365-modal-edit-wrapper",
  data() {
    return {
      list: {},
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.get_array_of_post_objects("applications");
  },
  methods: {
    get_array_of_post_objects(slug) {
      wp.api.loadPromise.done(function() {
        const Posts = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
          url: wpApiSettings.root + "fh/v1/menus/" + slug,
        });
        const all_posts = new Posts();
        all_posts.fetch().then(handlePostSuccess);
    },
    handlePostSuccess(post){
      console.log(posts.data);
      this.list = posts.data;
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Another Alternative is just use ```var self = this;``` in the start of your ```get_array_of_post_objects``` function so that you can just call ```self.list = posts.data;``` at the end